# how to catch Spinbox event of change value in QML?

Tags: qt, events, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

Subj
I show my data on QML' Listview with delegated text, labels, and spinboxvalue elements of item. When user change the value of spinbox I need to know it and make some deals. But MouseArea works beyond of Spinbox, not on spinned buttons, onClicked event doesn't exists.

```
SpinBox {
                    id: goodsCountSpinBox
                    leftPadding: 1
                    rightPadding: 1
                    value: model.goodsCount
                    implicitWidth: 100
                    anchors.right: dataRow.right
                    MouseArea {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        onClicked: {
                            listView.currentIndex = index; //Change the current selected item to the clicked item
                            console.log("SpinBox::MouseArea::onClicked")
                        }
                    }
```

By the way, and how to out current datetime in console log?

I found onValueChanged in examples but I don't find it in QML manuals.

```
  SpinBox {
            id: fontSizeSpinBox
            activeFocusOnPress: false
            implicitWidth: 50
            value: 0
            property bool valueGuard: true
            onValueChanged: if (valueGuard) document.fontSize = value
        }
```

I found to print current timestamp

```
   Qt.formatTime(new Date()
```

Comment: `onValueChanged` is a [property change signal handler](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-signals.html#property-change-signal-handlers).

Comment: thanks. it is a common information for all class objects.
now I understand
on<Property>Changed where <Property> is the name of the property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to just use the current value of the spinbox, just use its `value` property in a binding.

If you want to react to the value change, use the handler for the property's change signal, i.e. `onValueChanged`.